# Error while downloading plugin from eclipse oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse

I have eclipse oxygen and JDK 8 installed however I am having trouble in downloading any plugin e.g tomcat plugin.If I try installing from eclipse marketplace I am getting below error

> HTTP Server Unknown HTTP Response Code (301):http://tomcatplugin.sf.net/update/content.xml
>   General connection error with response code=301 and header(0)=HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

Comment: `http://tomcatplugin.sf.net/update/content.xml ` doesn't exist. There is a problem with that plugin, can you install other plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience is that the eclipse market place is not very stable and often have issues trying to install software for whatever reason. I suggest you install a different route by downloading the zipped archive site of the plugin below.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/tomcatplugin/files/latest/download?source=files

This will give a you zipped archive of a update site that you download locally. Once downloaded go back into your Eclipse IDE and go to Help -> Install New Software. In the dialog that appears click on "Add.." in the top right corner and another popup appears, click on "Archive.." (button on the left side near the bottom) and point to your zip file that was downloaded using the file explorer dialog. After doing that you'll see a Tomcat Plugin tree node in the main viewer, select it, then click on Next to install and that should do the tick!

- Duncan Krebs

Comment: Nice! Please up vote my answer if it worked for you by clicking the UP arrow next to the question.